# Prevent Visual Studio Code from exposing your Full Name on GitHub public repos

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am rather dismayed at the default behaviour of Visual Studio Code where if you contribute to a public GitHub repo, without asking for your permission VS Code pulls your Full Name from the profile of the computer you are working on and exposes your full name (NOT your GitHub account name) onto the public internet.

Living in Europe, this is very likely a violation of GDPR law. Does anyone know how to prevent this undesirable behaviour from happing in future?

NB I have looked at all the VS Code .json config files and the application settings in the app and nowhere does an option exit to prevent this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `git config --global` or `git config --local` to set `user.email` and `user.name`

Open a terminal and change the directory of the repository you want to change and type these commands

```
git config --local user.name "Any Joe"
git config --local user.email "any.joe@anonymouse.com"
```

Comment: I've looked at the usage instructions for the 'git config' command but it doesn't even mention how I would set those details. I'm new to VS Code so I'm still at a loss how to run those command snippets you've mentioned. 

Can you provide the full command e.g. to change my name to for examples sake: 'Any Joe' and email 'any.joe@anonymouse.com' for the Local config (not global) ?